# are these brackets necessary in old san francisco homes? Were they just used for framing and not removed?

Tags: wood, basement

Are these brackets necessary? This is in an old San Francisco two story home and these are attached to flooring. Were they just used for framing and not removed? I want to remove them to make way for easier shelving. [image]

Comment: Remember, San Fransisco is in the heart of earthquake territory. You don't want to remove parts of your house that help resist the little tremors you get on a regular basis around there.

Comment: I'd be interested to know more about this technique. I'm not familiar. Normally the floor sheathing provides more than enough diagonal stability.

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT remove them.

They are NOT old framing brackets. They are part of the roof structure.

If you have an area where you can see all the roof beams and trusses complete they are a complete structure - often very similar to a ship's construction upside down.

Comment: this is a two story home, these are attached to flooring. On the second story the roof has an additional 2ft crawl space.

Comment: Can I replace these with steel L Brackets from Simpson? I forgot to mention this wall is against another house that's lower than my house. The houses are side by side on a hill. This area would be resting against the neighbors roof corner.

Comment: @DaleLin I suggest you get a structural engineer or architect in to explain what you can and cannot do. I am not going to suggest anything else.

Answer (score 3):

By removing the cladding above, you'll be able to see that they are indeed attached to the joists above. Removing them will weaken the structure, as they are making the triangle which keeps the roof and walls stable. If they were anything else - merely holding things in place during construction, for example, they'd have been removed years ago. Use them to build/support your shelving.